# Catching exceptions from async methods (in a Caliburn.Micro context with MEF loaded assemblies)

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, mef, caliburn.micro

I have a Caliburn.Micro application that is set up to use MEF.
In the ViewModel that is first loaded, I loop through classes (interfaces) from various assemblies that have been loaded by MEF.
In one of these classes there is a method defined as an async task:

```
private async Task SomeAsyncMethod()
```

If this method throws an exception it is never caught by the override of `OnUnhandledException` in the bootstrapper, or anywhere else.

How do I define a global exception handler to catch this exception?

### AppBootstrapper.cs

Implemented as described here: https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customizing%20The%20Bootstrapper

Plus addition of the folder containing the additional assemblies to be loaded to the Configure override, and adding OnUnhandledException

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    AggregateCatalog aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>());
    aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExternalComponents"]));
    _container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);

    CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();

    batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
    batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
    batch.AddExportedValue(_container);

    _container.Compose(batch);
}

protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
}

protected override void OnUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Exceptions from async methods are not caught here
    MyLogger.Error(e.Exception, "Unhandled exception");
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

### Main view model

```
public class MainViewModel : IShell
{
    [ImportMany]
    private IEnumerable<IMyMefClass> _myMefClasses;

    protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
    {
        foreach (IMyMefClass instance in _myMefClasses)
        {
            instance.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

### MEF loaded class with async method

```
[Export(typeof(IMyMefClass))]
public class MyMefClassImplementation : IMyMefClass
{
    public void Start()
    {
        SomeAsyncMethod();
    }

    private async Task SomeAsyncMethod()
    {
        throw new Exception("This is never caught");
    }
}
```

The question is still, as above, how do I define a global exception handler to catch this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, juste rewrite your OnViewLoaded method:

```
protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
{
    var runningTasks =  _myMefClasses.Select(m=>m.Start()).ToArray();
    try
    {
        Task.WaitAll(runningTasks);
    }
    catch(AggregateException ex)
    {
        //Any exception raised by a task will be in ex.InnerExceptions
    }
}
```

This solution also has the advantage of letting all tasks run in parallel.

Comment: I was able to get my application to do a variant of this. However, if `SomeAsyncMethod()` does `return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new Exception() });`, then that exception is not caught up in `OnViewLoaded()`. So I guess I need to lay down some guidelines for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple solution:

```
public class MyMefClassImplementation : IMyMefClass
{
    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            await SomeAsyncMethod();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw ex
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Not really an optimal solution as you have to use await to catch the exception. Also, when someone else develops another IMyMefClass they're not always guaranteed to add exception handling.

Comment: That requirement was not part of your question. Anyway, see my other solution that solves your requirement of catching exceptions on any IMyMefCall that willl be developed later on.